# conversion of unicode string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, unsigned, signed

I need to convert unicode strings in Python to other types such as unsigned and signed int 8 bits,unsigned and signed int 16 bits,unsigned and signed int 32 bits,unsigned and signed int 64 bits,double,float,string,unsigned and signed 8 bit,unsigned and signed 16 bit, unsigned and signed 32 bit,unsigned and signed 64 bit.

I need help from u people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) to convert the string to an integer. Python doesn't have different fixed-width integers so you'll just get one type of thing out.

Then use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to pack the integer into a fixed width:

```
res = struct.pack("=B",i) ## uint8_t
res = struct.pack("=b",i) ## int8_t

res = struct.pack("=H",i) ## uint16_t
res = struct.pack("=h",i) ## int16_t

res = struct.pack("=I",i) ## uint32_t
res = struct.pack("=i",i) ## int32_t

res = struct.pack("=Q",i) ## uint64_t
res = struct.pack("=q",i) ## int64_t

res = struct.pack("=f",i) ## float
res = struct.pack("=d",i) ## double
```

`struct` produces a byte-string containing the number in binary.

EDIT:
From the comments it sounds like you just want to convert the string (of decimal digits) into an integer. Just use `int()` for that, however you won't get all the complicated overflow/underflow semantics of the specified types. You can't reproduce that in python, at least not without writing a whole lot of code.

I think if you want any more help you'll have to be more precise about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Douglas: I admire your psychic abilities (that, or your luck :). I still can't see a direct connection from the question —as specified— to “use int() to convert the string to an integer”… I would only suggest the struct module.

Comment: but type of res is string.
So i m not able to do any operations on it.
I m converting here to perform such arithmetic operations.
Its not possible.