# need help - bit-field conversion

Tags: python, string, bit, bit-fields

I want to convert strings to bit-fields.Also,convert them to binary and then use.
Need help with this..help me ..

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385572/need-help-typecasting-in-python

Answer (score 2):

I think the [struct module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-struct.html) is what you're after.

Example of usage:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> unpack('hhl', '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
>>> calcsize('hhl')
8
```

Answer (score 0):

they're all binary already... Which language are we talking about?

I'd start by looking at the string as an array of characters and working with each character individually.

Comment: @Cogsy - Language is Python.  Question not really sensible.