# Simulating C#'s sbyte (8 bit signed integer) casting in Python

Tags: c#, python, casting

In C#, I can cast things to 8bit signed ints like so:

```
(sbyte)arg1;
```

which when `arg1 = 2`, the cast returns 2 also. However, obviously casting `128` will return `-128`. More specifically casting `251` will return `-5`.

What's the best way to emulate this behavior?

Edit: Found a duplicate question: [Typecasting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385572/need-help-typecasting-in-python)

```
s8 = (i + 2**7) % 2**8 - 2**7      // convert to signed 8-bit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ctypes:

```
from ctypes import cast, pointer, c_int32, c_byte, POINTER
cast(pointer(c_int32(arg1)), POINTER(c_byte)).contents.value
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) module of the Python standard library, which, as so often, comes in handy for turning values into bytes and viceversa:

```
>>> def cast_sbyte(anint):
    return struct.unpack('b', struct.pack('<i', anint)[0])[0]
... ... 
>>> cast_sbyte(251)
-5
```

Comment: Hmm this is slower then the method I found in my OP :S.

Answer (score 0):

[struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module can help you, e.g. here is a way to convert int(4 bytes) to 4 signed bytes

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('i',251)
'\xfb\x00\x00\x00'
>>> s=struct.pack('i',251)
>>> print struct.unpack('bbbb',s)
(-5, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from numpy import int8
>>> int8(251)
-5
```

Comment: Any ideas off the top of your head how fast this would be compared with other solutions? Never used numpy.

Comment: Loading NumPy takes a few seconds, but its routines are implemented in C and Fortran.

Comment: Hmm oddly this is slower then Alex's method, and the one I found in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
>>> sbyte=lambda n:(255 & n^128)-128 
>>> # or sbyte=lambda n:(n+128 & 255)-128

>>> sbyte(251)
-5
>>> sbyte(2)
2
```