# Assignment values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why does

```
a = 3
b = 5
a,b = a + b,a   
print a,b
-------
8 3
```

differ from

```
a = 3
b = 5
a = a + b
b = a
print a,b
------
8 8
```

Can someone explain how Python interprets the assignments differently? Does Python still keep the old value of a in the first paragraph of code, when a is assigned to `a + b?` `(a= a+b)`

Also, does these assignment properties change from `Python 2 to Python 3?`

Comment: expressions are evaluated from right to left. So `a` isn't assigned until the right `a` is evaluated. There is a duplicate of this somewhere.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844487/swap-2-values-of-2-variables-without-using-a-third-variable-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python I am not going to hammer but this seems like a dupe.

Comment: you're not going to hammer... because I already did :) added your question as well.

Comment: COLDSPEED called me "the king of the dupehammer". I'm flattered, but now I have to make it worth :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry im new here but what are the repercussions of a dupe question, gotta be careful next time..

Comment: No repercussions unless a lot of questions you ask are heavily downvoted or duplicates. Asking the question to google often brings you to a SO answer. That avoids a lot of duplicates

Comment: you can read about account suspensions on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250076/account-suspended-for-1-year-is-this-correct. Be careful, see [ask], and you won't have any problems! this isn't a site made of fascists :)