# Multiple assignment in Python for Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

Recently I encountered the following multiple assignment, and have no idea how it swaps two nodes. I want to swap two nodes in a linked list. The code is :

```
head, head.next = head.next, head
```

as seen on https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/discuss/171788/Python-or-Dummynode

Can someone break down the steps and tell me how that code swaps head and head.next? It's very confusing to me.

Comment: first, it makes a copy of `head.next` and head which are on the right side the `=`. then assigns them to variables on the left side of `=` respectively.

Comment: This question contains a detailed explanation of this in general  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844487/swap-2-values-of-2-variables-without-using-a-third-variable-python In your context it works the same way.

Comment: @mrEvgenX I am aware of how multiple assignments are used in variables, but I do not quite understand how they are used in linked lists. After all, linked lists have to be linked. I am wondering how are they still linked after the multiple assignment.

Comment: @prhmma it does not make copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this a little bit and came up with the explanation.

```
head, head.next = head.next, head
```

is equivalent to the code

```
bob = head.next
alice = head
head = bob
head.next = alice
```

In other words, it takes a snapshot (or evaluates) of head.next and head (represented by bob and alice respectively), and allocates them to head and head.next

Expanding out the multiple assignment helped me to understand what it does.