# U8,U16,U32 representation in python

Tags: python, struct

I have two questions and they both are inter-related.

My first question is:
As for example, I have to declare few U8 variables, U16 and U48 and then have to pass the values to them. After passing the values, I have to covert them into a binary (one binary-all of them combined). I don't know how to perform this task
How to define U8, U16 and U32 in python(in binary). I know `struct` as a module. But when I write

```
ex=binascii.hexlify(struct.pack("I",1))
```

it returns `b'01000000'` instead of returning `01000000`. Is there any other way to do it(I need it in U8 format)

My second question is:

How can disintegrate **U8** into **2MSbits** and **6LSbits**

Comment: This is the correct output. `b` stands for bytes. It's not a part of the string.

Comment: What do mean by defining U8 in python? Python natively doesn't have a `byte` type like c/java, there is `array` `ctypes` and `numpy` but it helps to know what your goal is.

Comment: [Need help-typecasting in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385572/need-help-typecasting-in-python)  is this the same thing too

Comment: @simonzack   Can I disintegrate U8 into MSB and LSB. is it possible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about your goal? I don't think anyone else except you knows what you're asking about.

Comment: @MichałF I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to declare few U8 variables, U16 and U48 and then have to pass the values to them.

Python is a dynamic-typed language to a variable doesn't have a fixed type, the type of your value will depend on the value it holds. That said, in python there is a single integer type (`int`), and it can hold any signed integer number, if your number is to big it will be automatically converted to a bigint.

E.g.

```
var1 = 256  # A plain integer
var2 = 4294967296L # Bigger than 2**31, it has to be prefixed with an L
```

Since there is a single integer type, if you want to limit your variable to hold a given binary width, you should mask the LSBits.

E.g.

```
bignum = 2**50 - 1
only_8_lsb = bignum & 0xFF
only_16_lsb = bignum & 0xFFFF
only_48_lsb = bignum & (2**49 - 1)
```

> After passing the values, I have to covert them into a binary (one binary-all of them combined).

Technically, the numbers are already stored as binary. If you want to show the binary representation of a number, you'll have to hold it in a string, and you can use formatting

E.g. Converting a number to a zero-paded 8-digits binary representation

```
> "{0:08b}".format(0b11000011)
'11000011'
```

E.g. Converting a number to a zero-paded 16-digits binary representation

```
> "{0:016b}".format(0xCAFE)
'1100101011111110'
```

Hopefully, you noticed that a you can specify an integer in different ways.

> How can disintegrate U8 into 2MSbits and 6LSbits

Unless you need other representation, use bit operators as noted in the other answer.

`struct` has other purpose, it allows you to convert some python values to a string of bytes, as would other languages will see them in memory. And you are getting a `b` prefixed string, because in Python 3 `str` is meant to store unicode code points while [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) are meant to store raw bytes (sequences of "numbers" in the range `0 <= chr > 256`).

Comment: So that means I don't have to use `struct`

Comment: Using `struct` to convert a number to binary will be a two process step. `struct` will only give you a raw string of bytes (e.g. `struct.pack("I", 0xA1B2C3D4)` => `'\xd4\xc3\xb2\xa1'`) and you'll need to post-process it to be a binary representation. The only benefit of `struct` I can think of is to get the bytes in a specifc [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want, but you can extract the MSB and LSB using bit operations.

For a byte:

- 2 MSBs: `x >> 6`
- 6 LSBs: `x & ((1 << 6) - 1)`